# SQL Wordpress - select from wp_usermeta rows

Tags: sql, wordpress

I am trying to display some data from the `wp_usermeta` table.

Current code is:

```
SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = "user_general_first_name"
```

This will display the first name, but how can i add the last name to this?

Help is much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the last name as well, you can add something like

`... WHERE meta_key IN ('first_name', 'last_name')`

However, if you are looking for all of the first and last names in the table, I would modify your query a bit

`SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE meta_key IN ('first_name', 'last_name') ORDER BY user_id`

This would give you whether it was a first or last name and group them both together by person (user_id)

Answer (score 0):

Insert data into wordpress wp_users and wp_usermeta table from
different database's table.

```
<?php
/* 
Template Name: SQL Templatess
*/
get_header();
global $wpdb;

/**
 * Function is used to select fields from BarZap and ICMOrders database.
 */
function selectDatas($Fields) {
    global $wpdb;
    $slectSQL = "SELECT $Fields
    FROM barZapp.Venue AS venue
    INNER JOIN ICMOrders.Customer AS customer ON customer.ID = venue.CustomerId
    INNER JOIN ICMOrders.Order AS orderP ON customer.ID = orderP.CustomerID
    WHERE orderP.OrderType='BarZapp' GROUP BY orderP.CustomerID";
    return $slectSQL;
}

$insert4User = selectDatas("customer.ID,customer.Name,venue.password,customer.EmailAddress,venue.creationdate,venue.country,
    venue.state, venue.city, venue.zip, venue.contactphone");
$selectQuery = $wpdb->get_results($insert4User, OBJECT );

foreach ($selectQuery as $keyValues) {
    $result = $wpdb->insert( 
        $wpdb->prefix . 'users', 
        array( 
            'spam'            => 0, 
            'user_status'     => 0, 
            'deleted'         => 0, 
            'old_user_id'     =>$keyValues->ID,
            'user_login'      =>$keyValues->Name, 
            'user_pass'       =>$keyValues->password,
            'user_nicename'   =>$keyValues->Name, 
            'user_email'      =>$keyValues->EmailAddress, 
            'display_name'    =>$keyValues->Name, 
            'user_registered' =>$keyValues->creationdate, 
        )
    );
        $user_id = $wpdb->insert_id; ## Get the last inserted ID of user's
        $forUserrole = new WP_User( $user_id );

        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'nickname', $keyValues->Name);
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', $keyValues->Name);
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'rich_editing', true);
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'admin_color', 'fresh');
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'use_ssl', 0);
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'show_admin_bar_front', 0);
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'ic_capabilities', $forUserrole->set_role('Multi')); 
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'ic_user_level', 0);
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', $keyValues->Name);
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_email',$keyValues->EmailAddress);
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', $keyValues->contactphone);
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_state', $keyValues->state);
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', $keyValues->city);
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_zip', $keyValues->zip);
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_country', $keyValues->country);
}
get_footer();
```